# Xpath - identify text that contains string 'AB' in 5th and 6th characters of a word

Tags: xpath

I am trying to write a matching **XPath** rule but I can't seem to pin point words with the exact letters in the 5th and 6th position.

example 'ab' in 'qwer**ab**qwert'

```
/location1[Variable='variable1'][item1[contains(.,'AB')] or item1[contains(.,'ab')]
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `substring()` function in the below way:

```
/location1[Variable='variable1'][item1[substring(., 5, 2) = ('AB', 'ab')]]
```